# Multicolumn index for where and order by clause (postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

Consider the query like this:

```
select ... from table where a = 1 and b > 2 order by c asc
```

What would be the ideal idex for this query?
Should i use one index (a, b, c) or two separate (a, b) and (c)?

thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on the statistics of the data and how many rows are selected.  However, I would expect `(a, b)` to be optimal under many circumstances.

Comment: @GordonLinoff But ordering supposed to benefit from indexing too... does the second condition '>' breaks the index scan?

Comment: . . It is tricky sometimes to have an index used for sorting when there are inequalities in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't do both well.  The equality is not a problem, but you can't cleanly combine inequality with ordering.  How many rows do you expect to return?  If `b>2` is very selective leaving few rows left to sort, then clearly you want want `(a,b)` as getting the selectivity is useful while sorting the few remaining rows doesn't take very long.  On the other hand, if `b>2` only rules out a few rows, then `(a,c)` (perhaps with more columns at the end to allow index-only scans) avoids a big slow sort while removing the few rows that fail b "the hard way" doesn't take very long.

You could build both and let the planner make the call, although it is far from perfect at doing so.

It is possible to use a GiST index on all three columns to achieve both the inequality filtering and the ordering simultaneously, but GiST indexes have a much higher overhead than BTree indexes as well as being slower to build and maintain, so it is quite unlikely to be worth while, although if you used a LIMIT that could make it more attractive.  You would also need to write the query in a contorted way, as a KNN query (assisted by the [btree_gist](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html) extension):

```
where a = 1 and b > 2 order by c <-> impossibly_low_value
```

There are other advanced possibilities.  If the thing you compare b to is always `>2`, then you could use a partial index `(a,c) where b>2` or an expression index `(a,(b>2),c)`.  You might also be able to usefully partition on b.  If b has a small number of distinct values, you could just UNION ALL the results of queries on each qualifying distinct value and use the index on `(a,b,c)`, getting an efficient merge append:

```
(select * from foo where a=1 and b=3 order by c asc) 
    union all 
(select * from foo where a=1 and b=4 order by c asc) 
order by c asc;
```

Comment: Will the `UNION` approach really help with sorting?

Comment: It was to be UNION ALL, not just UNION.  It provides order without doing a sort at all, by preserving the index ordering.  How effective it is depends on how clustered the table is, and on sequential vs random page costs.  Of course the effectiveness is most pronounced when there is a LIMIT specified.

Comment: I mean, if you get two sorted results (using the index) and then `UNION ALL` them, the result has to be sorted again (like you did in your answer). But then you might as well omit the `ORDER BY` in the subqueries, and the index will not be used for sorting the overall result.